# Using ExportToJPEG to plot multiple raster files with arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I am trying to use `arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG` to convert some raster files to jpeg format. I am new to this module. I am using the following script:

```
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"E:/analysis/maps/new_cs_rivnat/c1_s1/53_cities.mxd")
arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd, r"E:/analysis/maps/new_cs_rivnat/c1_s1/test.jpg")
```

In the `53_cities.mxd`, there are 12 raster files and I want to convert all these, How can I do that? This script only converts the first raster.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to set up a loop to run over each of the rasters you want to export.

Here is **one** option, this uses vectors...but it could be tweaked to use a raster instead.

```
import arcpy
import os

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"Full path to mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]

for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd):   
    ext = lyr.getExtent()
    df.extent = ext
    rounded = (round(df.scale/500)*500) + 500
    df.scale = rounded
    
    #jpg_name = os.path.join("Path and name of new jpg...") an example:
    jpg_name = os.path.join(r"c:\temp",lyr.name +".jpg")

    resolution = "150"

    arcpy.mapping.ExportToJPEG(mxd,jpg_name,resolution = 200)
del mxd
del df
print ("Done")
```

I havent been able to test this, it is a mix and match out of a script I used to use. You might need to perform a search and zoom to, before setting the zoom extent / scale.